# How to solve this "RuntimeError: Failed to run torchinfo" when trying to get the summary of my SegNet architechture?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, python-3.7

Can anyone help me with this error?

I want to see the summary of my deeplearning architecture features which is SegNet that using PyTorch. I try the code that've been made by trypag from github (https://github.com/trypag/pytorch-unet-segnet). I use summary() from torchinfo made by TylerYep (https://github.com/TylerYep/torchinfo). It was fine with other architecture like vgg16, resnet50, even with the samples code in the repository. But when I try to use it with codes from trypag I get:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. Executed layers up to:
[Encoder: 2-1, Sequential: 3-1, Conv2d: 4-1, BatchNorm2d: 4-2, ReLU: 4-3, Conv2d: 4-4, BatchNorm2d: 4-5, 
ReLU: 4-6, Encoder: 2-2, Sequential: 3-2, Conv2d: 4-7, BatchNorm2d: 4-8, ReLU: 4-9, Conv2d: 4-10, BatchNorm2d: 4-11, 
ReLU: 4-12, Encoder: 2-3, Sequential: 3-3, Conv2d: 4-13, BatchNorm2d: 4-14, ReLU: 4-15, Conv2d: 4-16, 
BatchNorm2d: 4-17, ReLU: 4-18, Dropout: 4-19, Encoder: 2-4, Sequential: 3-4, Conv2d: 4-20, BatchNorm2d: 4-21, 
ReLU: 4-22, Conv2d: 4-23, BatchNorm2d: 4-24, ReLU: 4-25,` Dropout: 4-26, Encoder: 2-5, Sequential: 3-5, Conv2d: 4-27, 
BatchNorm2d: 4-28, ReLU: 4-29, Conv2d: 4-30, BatchNorm2d: 4-31, ReLU: 4-32, Dropout: 4-33, Decoder: 2-6, 
Sequential: 3-6, Conv2d: 4-34, BatchNorm2d: 4-35, ReLU: 4-36, Conv2d: 4-37, BatchNorm2d: 4-38, ReLU: 4-39, 
Dropout: 4-40, Decoder: 2-7, Sequential: 3-7, Conv2d: 4-41, BatchNorm2d: 4-42, ReLU: 4-43, Conv2d: 4-44, 
BatchNorm2d: 4-45, ReLU: 4-46, Dropout: 4-47, Decoder: 2-8, Sequential: 3-8, Conv2d: 4-48, BatchNorm2d: 4-49, 
ReLU: 4-50, Conv2d: 4-51, BatchNorm2d: 4-52, ReLU: 4-53, Dropout: 4-54, Decoder: 2-9, Sequential: 3-9, Conv2d: 4-55, 
BatchNorm2d: 4-56, ReLU: 4-57, Conv2d: 4-58, BatchNorm2d: 4-59, ReLU: 4-60, Conv2d: 4-61]
```

This is the code that I use:

```
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch

class SegNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, in_features = 1, drop_rate = 0.5,
                 filter_config=(64, 128, 256, 512, 512)):
        super(SegNet, self).__init__()
    
        self.encoders = nn.ModuleList()
        self.decoders = nn.ModuleList()
    
        encoder_n_layers = (2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
        encoder_filter_config = (in_features,) + filter_config
        decoder_n_layers = (3, 3, 3, 2, 1)
        decoder_filter_config = filter_config[::-1] + (filter_config[0],)
    
        for i in range(0, 5):
            self.encoders.append(Encoder(encoder_filter_config[i],
                                         encoder_filter_config[i + 1],
                                         encoder_n_layers[i], drop_rate))
        
            self.decoders.append(Decoder(decoder_filter_config[i],
                                         decoder_filter_config[i + 1],
                                         decoder_n_layers[i], drop_rate))
    
        self.classifier = nn.Conv2d(filter_config[0],  num_classes, kernel_size = 3, 
                                    stride = 1, padding = 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        indices = []
        unpool_sizes = []
        feat = x
    
        for i in range(0, 5):
            (feat, ind), size = self.encoders[i](feat)
            indices.append(ind)
            unpool_sizes.append(size)
        
        for i in range(0, 5):
            feat = self.decoders[i](feat, indices[4 - i], unpool_sizes[4 - i])
        
        return self.classifier(feat)

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    """

    A helper Module that performs ConvoBlock (Convolutional, BN, Activation).
    Maxpooling follows each ConvoBlock.

    """

    def __init__(self,
                 in_features: int,
                 out_features: int,
                 n_blocks: int = 2,
                 drop_rate = 0.5):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    
        layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_features, out_features, kernel_size = 3,
                            stride = 1, padding = 1, bias = True),
                  nn.BatchNorm2d(out_features),
                  nn.ReLU(inplace = True)]
    
        if n_blocks > 1:
            layers += [nn.Conv2d(out_features, out_features, kernel_size = 3, 
                                 stride = 1, padding = 1, bias = True),
                       nn.BatchNorm2d(out_features),
                       nn.ReLU(inplace = True)]
            if n_blocks == 3:
                layers += [nn.Dropout(drop_rate)]
    
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.features(x)
        return F.max_pool2d(output, kernel_size = 2, stride = 2, return_indices = 
                            True), output.size()

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 in_features: int,
                 out_features: int,
                 n_blocks: int = 2,
                 drop_rate = 0.5):
    
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    
        layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_features, out_features, kernel_size = 3,
                            stride = 1, padding = 1, bias = True),
                  nn.BatchNorm2d(out_features),
                  nn.ReLU(inplace = True)]
    
        if n_blocks > 1:
             layers += [nn.Conv2d(out_features, out_features, kernel_size = 3, 
                                 stride = 1, padding = 1, bias = True),
                       nn.BatchNorm2d(out_features),
                       nn.ReLU(inplace = True)]
            if n_blocks == 3:
                 layers += [nn.Dropout(drop_rate)]
    
         self.features = nn.Sequential(*layers)
    
    def forward(self, x, indices, size):
        unpooled = F.max_unpool2d(x, indices = indices, kernel_size = 2,  stride = 2, 
                                  padding = 0, output_size = size)
        return self.features(unpooled)


 device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = SegNet(num_classes = 2, in_features = 3).to(device)
x = torch.randn(size = (1, 3, 360, 480), 
                dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
with torch.no_grad():
    out = model(x)

from torchinfo import summary

summary = summary(model, (32, 3, 360, 480))
```

This part of code is only for testing to display the summary:

```
model = SegNet(num_classes = 2, in_features = 3).to(device)
x = torch.randn(size = (1, 3, 360, 480), 
                dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
with torch.no_grad():
    out = model(x)

from torchinfo import summary

summary = summary(model, (32, 3, 360, 480))
```

Should I trace the error by looking the code behind torchinfo summary() then revised my code? Or any other advice for me?

Any advice or solution will help me alot.
Thank You !

Comment: If it is not already the case, try to set `device='cpu'` inside the summary function, this would prevent bugs. Then you just have to send you model again to the desired device.